# Can't import qiskit.aqua in IBM quantum experience

Tags: qiskit

[I am getting this error on IBM quantum experience and am not sure why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/591lr.png)

Comment: Your post should be more than a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Qiskit Aqua was deprecated last year, and as of the end of last year removed from Qiskit and is no longer distributed or supported. See https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html#qiskit-0-33-0 Aqua was moved/refactored so its function exists elsewhere as the release note outlines.

In regards to Shor, the algorithms were moved into core Qiskit (Terra) and you can find its API reference here now https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/algorithms.html#factorizers